# Call root.destroy() from a child thread

Tags: python, tkinter

The program below simply tests whether I can call root.destroy() of tkinter in a child thread. Though no error raised, I see a lot of posts in stackoverflow reminding people not to use tkinter in a child thread, so I wonder if calling root.destroy() in a child thread is not a good idea too, though I used tkinter in the main thread?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import _thread

def callBackFunc():
    global LOOP_ACTIVE
    LOOP_ACTIVE = False
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
chkValue = tkinter.BooleanVar()
chkValue.set(False)
chk = ttk.Checkbutton(root, variable=chkValue, text='Click me', command=callBackFunc)
chk.grid(column=0, row=0)

def loop_function():
    global LOOP_ACTIVE
    LOOP_ACTIVE = True
    while LOOP_ACTIVE:
        print(chk.state())
        time.sleep(5)
    print("you clicked me")
    root.destroy()
_thread.start_new_thread(loop_function, ())
root.mainloop()
print("printed after mainloop ends")
```

Comment: None of the UI frameworks support doing UI operations on a secondary thread.  Windows is fairly forgiving about it, Linux tends to work until it crashes, Mac hates it.  The general rule is, don't do it.

Comment: so is there a way that i can call root.destroy() right after the secondary thread dies?

Comment: You can try using `root.event_generate("<Destroy>")` instead of calling `root.destroy()` directly.

Comment: is there a way i can prevent writing destroy codes inside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid calling `destroy()` in the child thread by periodically checking the flag in the main GUI thread by using the universal [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) widget method to schedule them to occur.

In the code below I've added a `check_loop_status()` function that does that, and *it* will call `root.destroy()` if it discovers that the `LOOP_ACTIVE` flag is no longer set. To keep on process going, it schedules another call to itself before returning (which of course will never happen if `destroy()` got called).

Since this all that happens in the main thread, any call to `destroy()` will be fine.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import _thread

DELAY = 1000 # milliseconds

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

chkValue = tkinter.BooleanVar(value=False)

def callBackFunc():
    global LOOP_ACTIVE
    print("button was clicked")
    LOOP_ACTIVE = False

def check_loop_status():
    global LOOP_ACTIVE
    if not LOOP_ACTIVE:
        root.destroy()  # OK in this function.
    root.after(DELAY, check_loop_status)  # Check again after delay.

chk = ttk.Checkbutton(root, variable=chkValue, text='Click me', command=callBackFunc)
chk.grid(column=0, row=0)

def loop_function():
    global LOOP_ACTIVE
    while LOOP_ACTIVE:
        print(f'Checkbutton state: {chk.state()}')
        time.sleep(5)

LOOP_ACTIVE = True
_thread.start_new_thread(loop_function, ())
check_loop_status()  # Start periodic checking.
root.mainloop()
print("printed after mainloop ends")
```